# Where is this page to manage my email subscriptions?

Tags: bug, email-notification

This recent email from do-not-reply@stackexchange.com contains "Unsubscribe" (underlined - upper left hand corner):

[image]

A click shows a box containing: "Stack Exchange provides a page at meta.stackexchange.com where you can manage your email subscriptions."

[image]

The link brings me to meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/2413237/… and it tells me (without any further ado): `You have been unsubscribed You have successfully unsubscribed, you will no longer receive daily updates about your inbox.` (This is unnecessarily verbose but an interesting linguistic pattern: passive voice followed by active voice with the same verb.)

To change my SO email settings I can go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/NNNNNNN.

So, where is that page the text in the box refers to? Could it be that the message text is incorrect?

Comment: What kind of email exactly? Can you give a screenshot, or the exact link you get in the email?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Uploaded screen shot. The link in the popup box is http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where are you taken when clicking "Unsubscribe"? What is the link?

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe/inbox/2413237/396dc074ca526b1f084a2c5b46720173cd2a840421061e3afb8cf5e2615f87d1 and it tells me `You have been unsubscribed
You have successfully unsubscribed, you will no longer receive daily updates about your inbox`. (This is an interesting linguistic pattern: passive voice followed by active voice with the same verb.)

Comment: Weird. Please add this info to your post, and hopefully a dev will take a look and fix if it's really a bug.

Answer (score 4):

This is a gmail feature that Stack Exchange started to use recently. You can read about the feature itself [here](http://marketingland.com/everything-need-know-gmails-auto-unsubscribe-75605).

In case of unread inbox items, the subscription is made per site but the inbox is global, so it's causing a problem: there is no one place to manage all sites preferences.

I guess Stack Exchange put as the "unsubscribe header" the last site where you turned on the inbox notifications, so while not the best experience, not sure it's a bug.

To further dig into this, try to untick "Email me my unread inbox messages" [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current), wait for a new email, and see if it's pointing to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Re your "I guess" I'm getting a little confused. The mail is referring to **SO** comments(!); it is titled "Stack Exchange" (the "umbrella" name, right?), and the unsubscribe link goes to meta-SW. I've never actively requested email notifications for *comments*. - Anyway, I've deselected notifications for comments on my SO profile page (again: I've never *selected* this). I very much dislike "blessings" that crop up without asking or being asked for (not the interesting linguistic pattern).

Comment: The email is your unread inbox items. Inbox items means Stack Exchange inbox items, which are comments, answers on your questions, etc, and it's global for all sites. On every site, you see the whole inbox with all notifications from all other sites you have account in.

Comment: Let's say I am interested in topic "Drools" in SO. I'm happily receiving emails pointing to the recent `"Drools" feed`. Suddenly, without my request, I receive a notification about *comments* to my recent activities (as it happened). I don't want any more emails *about comments* - so I decide to "Unsubscribe". I'm pretty sure, this will turn off everything from SO, right?

Comment: Those are two totally different things. The email you posted screenshot of is direct result of you going to your Stack Overflow profile, edit, and ticking "Email me my unread inbox messages" then saving. Emails for tags are managed elsewhere.

Comment: I never went to my SO profile, ticking anything about unread inbox messages, let alone saving it. I went there, after receiving this email, to untick it. (Don't take me for a nincompoop. I wrote my first program in 1966, probably a few years before your pa met your ma.)

Comment: And you sure you never ticked that box here as well, maybe as experiment? I find it hard to believe it will tick itself without a reason, though we're going a bit off topic from the original issue

Comment: 1966. 1966. 1966. Why the deuce would I? I'm getting enough emails as it is.

Comment: I give up. Good luck to you.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but if you aren't s.o. from the team implementing this you mayn't be able to shed some light on this. Merely trying to compare what-I-have with what-you-have isn't going to work. When were black-box testers ever able to pinpoint bugs in the code?

Comment: Thing is, Mr. @laune, that many times those aren't really bugs but misunderstanding how the system works. After few years of being active here, I got some experience in how things work, so were trying to explain what you experience assuming it's not a result of bug. But as it turns out we just reached a dead end, and now you're right, only SE developer can shed real light.